# network: CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: cannot find network namespace for the terminated container issue in EKS. help anybody, please

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, cni

When pods are increased through hpa, the following error occurs and pod creation is not possible.
If I manually change the replicas of the deployments, the pods are running normally.

It seems to be a CNI-related problem, and the same phenomenon occurs even if you install 1.7.10 cni for 1.20 cluster with add on .

200 IPs per subnet is sufficient, and the outbound security group is also open.
By default, that issue does not occur when the number of pods is scaled via kubectl .

7s          Warning   FailedCreatePodSandBox   pod/b4c-ms-test-develop-5f64db58f-bm2vc   Failed to create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "7632e23d2f3db8f8b8c0335aaaa6afe1e52ad43cf293bfa6789aa14f5b665cf1" network for pod "b4c-ms-test-develop-5f64db58f-bm2vc": networkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "b4c-ms-test-develop-5f64db58f-bm2vc_b4c-test" network: CNI failed to retrieve network namespace path: cannot find network namespace for the terminated container "7632e23d2f3db8f8b8c0335aaaa6afe1e52ad43cf293bfa6789aa14f5b665cf1"
Region: eu-west-1
Cluster Name: dev-pangaia-b4c-eks
For AWS VPC CNI issue, have you attached node logs?: No
For DNS issue, have you attached CoreDNS pod log?:

Comment: I solve this problem.  The cause was argo Cd prune setting